# How to apply probability to see if an event has occured or not

Tags: probability, statistics

It was asked in one of my facebook group pages about what everyone would think would be the total number of times event X will happen in the season.

I decided I wanted to nerd it out and try to figure out what X would be given the previous season's statistics and the probability it would happen this year through a C# program. I have applied the Binomial Distribution to get the probabilities needed but this is where I am stuck.

How do I use the probability to get a yes/no that the event will happen in that particular at-bat?

> IE: Batter A has a 22% chance of hitting a double per at-bat.
>
> At-bat #1: double
>
> At-bat #2: no double
>
> At-bat #3: no double

So we can say with certainty that in this particular game, batter A hit at least 1 double and we can add that 1 double to a running total for the # of occurrences it may be simulated to happen.

How would I do the above example mathematically?

as a side note: This is something for fun as I am a huge baseball enthusiast and in no way attached to any attempt at sports betting.

TIA!

Comment: What is “event X” in your example?

Comment: To use the Binomial distribution, you need the probability of the event occurring in a single trial. Why can’t you simply use the number of doubles divided by the number of at-bats for that?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang the question was to figure out how many times Battle A, B and C would hit a home run in the same game in a season. I have added other interests to it, but if I can simplify this to just figure out that main question, that would be good enough.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  So batters A, B, and C each have their own home-run-probability, and you want to know the probability of all of them hitting a home run in the same game.  That's probably a simpler question.

Comment: @amd Initially, I did that. I took the home runs per at-bat and ran a simulation to figure out how many times it would happen, however it came up with 0 times this would happen. I checked my simulation and the math and logic was sound which leads me to believe I needed to use a different set of statistics. So I took the slugging % (1*singles total + 2* double totals + 3 * triple totals + 4 * home run totals divided by the total At-bats) and eliminated the other metrics to only grab the slugging % based on home runs.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes and no, actually re-reading your comment, I don't want to just get the probability, I want to know that if they have a probability of doing it say 15% of the time, how many times would it occur given a 162 game season? or would I just take the 15% of 162?.

Comment: actually, I think i found some way to do this using a coin flip generator as a base for this simulation. It would net similar results to what I want.

Comment: Zero is not a plausible answer if all three probabilities of a home run per at bat are nonzero. If you came up with *exactly* zero, then there’s likely an error in your math and/or simulation. On the other hand, a *very* small probability is plausible, and if it’s small enough to dwarf the number of at-bats in a season, a simulation could very well come up with zero unless you run it for a *lot* of iterations. If the probability really is that small, it might make sense to change the question: is it a once-every 10 years event? once every 100? &c.

Comment: Anyway, working out the right slugging % doesn’t seem like the tricky part of this. You also need a model for the number of at-bats per game for each hitter.

Comment: well that's a simple google to be honest but I was standardizing it to the 3 at-bats that players see on average, though I suppose I can't do that as it would skew the data.